# How to call a function from one module to another Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I try to call a function from a module A to a module B
here is the module A code

```
namespace A\Epayment\Model;
  class Etransactions
    {
      public function customPayment{
        return "test";
      }
```

and module b code

```
  namespace B\Payment\Controller\Index;

class Payment extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_transaction;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \ETransactions\Epayment\Model\Etransactions $transaction
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_transaction = $transaction;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hello World".PHP_EOL;
        $foo="a";
        echo $foo;
        echo $this->_transaction->customPayment();
        //echo $this->customPayment();
        echo $foo;

        exit;
    }
}
```

this code return the "hello world", the first $foo, not the second and doesn't display any error

can someone explain me where is my error ?

EDIT: i didn't change anything but it works fine now. 
thanks for the answers anyway

Answer (score 0):

The object you want create the path your are injecting is incorrect.

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \A\Epayment\Model\Etransactions $transaction // changes are here
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_transaction = $transaction;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Kindly use exception handling.

```
try{
$this->_transaction->customPayment();
}catch(Exception $e){
//log your exception here.
}
```

Comment: it could had been that, but i've just forgoten to change it in the post.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, Helper classes are available to use anywhere (Block, Controller, Model, Observer, View). So you should create a method in helper class and call it anywhere by the following way.

**Declar the helper class and method:** `ModuleA\Epayment\Helper\Data`.

```
<?php
namespace ModuleA\Epayment\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function yourHelperMethod()
    {
        # code...
    }
}
```

**Call the method:**

```
$helper = $this->_objectManager->create(ModuleA\Epayment\Helper\Data::class);
$helper->yourHelperMethod();
```

**Note:** If the object manager is not injected in your class. Please follow the steps below:

**1) declare private property:**

```
private $_objectManager;
```

**2) inject in the constructor to initialize:**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
}
```

**3) use in some method:**

```
public function someMethod() {
    $helper = $this->_objectManager->create(ModuleA\Epayment\Helper\Data::class);
    $helper->yourHelperMethod();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i'll do it that way next time, but here i can't modify module A in that cas.
i dont know why but it works now without any changes ( although i've been flushing the cache, compiling and all before, it just started working now)